# tm_map(gsub...) fails to replace words

Tags: r, text-mining, term-document-matrix

````
# Loading required libraries


# Set up logistics such as reading in data and setting up corpus

```{r}

# Relative path points to the local folder
folder.path="../data/InauguralSpeeches/"

# get the list of file names
speeches=list.files(path = folder.path, pattern = "*.txt")

# Truncate file names so it is only showing "FirstLast-Term"
prez.out=substr(speeches, 6, nchar(speeches)-4)

# Create a vector NA's equal to the length of the number of speeches
length.speeches=rep(NA, length(speeches))

# Create a corpus
ff.all<-Corpus(DirSource(folder.path))
```

# Clean the data

```{r}

# Use tm_map to strip all white spaces to a single space, to lower case case, remove stop words, empty strings and punctuation.
ff.all<-tm_map(ff.all, stripWhitespace)
ff.all<-tm_map(ff.all, content_transformer(tolower))
ff.all<-tm_map(ff.all, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
ff.all<-tm_map(ff.all, removeWords, c("can", "may", "upon", "shall", "will",     "must", ""))
````

## The problem line

ff.all<-tm_map(ff.all, gsub, pattern = "free", replacement = "freedom")

```
ff.all<-tm_map(ff.all, removeWords, character(0))
ff.all<-tm_map(ff.all, removePunctuation)

# tdm.all =  a Term Document Matrix
tdm.all<-TermDocumentMatrix(ff.all)
```

So I am trying to replace words that are similar by one root word. For example, replacing "free" by "freedom" in a text mining project.

Then I learned this line from a Youtube tutorial: ff.all<-tm_map(ff.all, gsub, pattern = "free", replacement = "freedom").
Without this line, the code runs.

With this line added, R Studio gives this error "**Error: inherits(doc, "TextDocument") is not TRUE**" on the execution of this line: "*tdm.all<-TermDocumentMatrix(ff.all)*"

I think this should be a relatively simple issue, however I could not find a solution on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `tm`'s builtin `crude` data I was able to fix your problem by wrapping `gsub` in a `content_transformer` call like so.

```
ff.all<-tm_map(ff.all, content_transformer(function(x) gsub(x, pattern = "free", replacement = "freedom")))
```

It has been my experience that `tm_map` does wierd things to the returned object for custom functions. So while your original line worked `tm_map` doesn't quite return a true "Corpus" that is what causes the errors.

As a side note:

This line seems to do nothing
    ff.all<-tm_map(ff.all, removeWords, character(0))

Same with the `""` in 
    ff.all<-tm_map(ff.all, removeWords, c("can", "may", "upon", "shall", "will",     "must", ""))

#### My full example

```
library(tm)
data(crude)
ff.all <- crude

ff.all<-tm_map(ff.all, stripWhitespace)
ff.all<-tm_map(ff.all, content_transformer(tolower))
ff.all<-tm_map(ff.all, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
ff.all<-tm_map(ff.all, removeWords, c("can", "may", "upon", "shall", "will",     "must", ""))

ff.all<-tm_map(ff.all, content_transformer(function(x) gsub(x, pattern = "free", replacement = "freedom")))

ff.all<-tm_map(ff.all, removeWords, character(0))
ff.all<-tm_map(ff.all, removePunctuation)

# tdm.all =  a Term Document Matrix
tdm.all<-TermDocumentMatrix(ff.all)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It was a life-saver. And yes, that removing character(0) is redundant.